# A Typescript type for an object which its property values should match the property names?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Is it possible to define a Typescript type for an object that should have its `values` equals to its properties names?

Like:

```
const ACTION_TYPES= {
  UPDATE_STATE_A: "UPDATE_STATE_A",
  UPDATE_STATE_B: "UPDATE_STATE_B",
  UPDATE_STATE_C: "UPDATE_STATE_C",
  // AND SO ON...
}
```

**Note:** It's all strings. Both properties and values.

How can I define such type?

Comment: What's the use case here? It seems like this would make more sense as an *enum*.

Comment: Hi, it's for an `ACTION_TYPES` object. So it's `{UPDATE_SOME_STATE: "UPDATE_SOME_STATE"}` etc. How could I solve this with `enum`? I've read the docs but I've never used enums so far.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, this is possible:

```
type StrangeType<T extends {[key:string]:string}> = {
  [key in keyof T]: key
}

const test: StrangeType<{name:'t'}>= {
  name: 'name'
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a similar solution without generics?

Comment: I am not aware, but don't think it is possible.

Comment: Your solution requires me to know upfront the property names? Like you did with `name`?

Comment: Got your point now. As far as I know, you can't do this in place, sorry